# CSS3 Animations are working in all browsers but Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, webkit

Just starting into HTML and CSS design, but my attempts at using webkit animations have been stymied by a lack of cooperation on chromes part.

Iv'e done my best to make sure everything is formatted properly, but chrome is still obstinately showing a black box in place of the images I'm using.

Here www.wesleymartin.ca, just a personal website for practice, and the images in question are at the bottom. The desired effect, which is a fadeout when moused over, works in all browsers except chrome.

Heres the HTML code.

```
<table id="linkbar" border="0">
<th>
        <div class="brighten pic">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/wesley.martin.58">
          <img id ="linkpic" src="Link Pics/facebook.jpg" alt="sea">
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="brighten pic" style= "margin-left: 0px;>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/WesMartin10">
          <img id ="linkpic" src="Link Pics/twitter.png" alt="sea" >
          <style>margin-left: 0px:</style>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="brighten pic">
          <a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/wesley-martin/74/232/a3">
          <img id ="linkpic" src="Link Pics/linkedin.jpg" alt="sea">
          </a>
        </div>
</th>
</table>
<!--</div>-->
```

And the CSS.

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       -o-box-sizing: border-box;
      -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-image:url(background.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:right; 
    background-color: #996633;
}

.pic {
    border: 3px solid #999;  
    float: left;
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    margin: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/*DARKEN*/
.brighten img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0);
     -moz-filter: brightness(0);
       -o-filter: brightness(0);
      -ms-filter: brightness(0);
          filter: brightness(0);

  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all .1s ease;
       -o-transition: all .1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all .1s ease;
          transition: all .1s ease;
}

.brighten img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(-25%);
     -moz-filter: brightness(-25%);
       -o-filter: brightness(-25%);
      -ms-filter: brightness(-25%);
          filter: brightness(-25%);
}

#linkbar {      
    width: 358px; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-179px;
    background:#330000;
    border: 3px solid #999;
}

#linkpic {
    height:69px;        
}

#test {
    background:#330000;
    height: 400px;
    width:400px;
}
```

Comment: Other browsers are not showing black boxes because they do not support CSS3 filters! Black boxes are the correct output based on the code you have above.

Comment: Did my solutions help? Please mark it as the answer if it did.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 filter: brightness should be specified as a value between 0 and 1, where 0 is the darkest (black) and 1 is the brightest.

You are seeing black boxes because brightness 0 means 0% brightness.

What you want is this:

```
.brighten img {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(1);
     -moz-filter: brightness(1);
       -o-filter: brightness(1);
      -ms-filter: brightness(1);
          filter: brightness(1);
}

.brighten img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(.75);
     -moz-filter: brightness(.75);
       -o-filter: brightness(.75);
      -ms-filter: brightness(.75);
          filter: brightness(.75);
}
```

PS: I put .75 (AKA 75%) because I'm assuming that's what you meant by -25%, but you can obviously put any number.

EDIT:
Something to keep in mind:

It is my understanding that CSS3 filters are not supported by most browsers (not supported by Firefox, IE, Opera).
View this link for more info: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/filters/